# How to ship a command with a node_module

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I]m trying to do something which has been done in other projects, but not quite sure how its done. Basically lets say I have a nodemodule that you can install from a git repo, this module could be considered a mini framework. So in that framework I might have a service which is lets say:

- start a dev server
- create a file and a folder structure or something like so

So what I'm wanting to do is to ship a CLI command with the tool, this would allow the user to do something like "framework cmd ..." from the root of the project. I guess something like "react-native" when your in the root of the project.

How would you make something like this available, without having to require the user to run npm link or install something globally?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `bin` section in your package.json. There you can define the name of the cli command you want to provide.
This is very similar to the `script` section.

```
"bin": {
    "framework": "index.js"
}
```

When someone installs you package with npm or yarn, he will be able to call your cli command with just typing `framework ...`.

Comment: is there anything else I need to do? I've added the entry to my package.json and updated everything in my test project that uses the framework. But the command never works. Cmd not found

Comment: It depends, if you install the package globally, you need to make sure, that the global npm bin is in your `PATH`. You can get the path with  `npm bin -g`.
If you install it as dependency of your app, then since npm 5.2.0 you can just run `npx framework` in you app root.